# Asp .net core изменить js script с бекенда

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Есть ли механизм и возможность измненить js скрипт на лету?
Скрипт находится в wwwroot папке, нужно каким-то образом внедрить в него переменные.
Вариант с cshtml и прочие стандартные методики не подходят. 
Спасибо.

Пример: в wwwroot  лежит file.js c контентом

```
{ myVar: null }
```

Нужно чтоб при отдаче контент заменился на

```
{ myVar: "someValueFromBackEnd"}
```

Comment: Можно поподробнее с примером скрипта и что хочется получить в итоге? И почему не подходит вариант с cshtml?

Comment: @chromigo, добавил пример. По той причине, что у нас нету cshtml, а есть сгенеренный вебпаком фронт.

Comment: если данные динамически получаются с сервера, то просто делать ajax запрос на backend и тянуть оттуда нужные данные. 
Если запросы посылать не хочется это не очень простой кейс.
Если это просто фиксированные значения из конфига которые не меняются, или меняются руками и редко - можно попробовать парсить на бэкэнде получившийся бандл (а в случае его перегенерации снова парсить и менять значение). Но парсить этот бандл может оказаться не очень просто)

Comment: Могу вам предложить вариант с httpHandler, просто добавляете `<httpHandlers><add verb="*" path="*.js" type="YourJsHandler"` />` читаете файл сами, перерабатываете как вам угодно. Вам именно этот механизм показать? Вот "нулячий" есть https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms228090(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @nick_n_a это вариант для не-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В .net core для обработки любого запроса должен быть применен так называемый middleware обработкчик и содержимое папки wwwroot в проекте не исключение. Для этого вы подключаете одно из расширений, например UseStaticFiles в вашем startup.cs. Раз есть middleware значит есть выходной поток который можно перед отправкой клиенту модифицировать по своему усмотрению (например так работает middleware по динамическому сжатию ответа).

Все что вам нужно это правильно подменить исходящий поток предоставляемый инфраструктурой .net core на спроектированный вами класс наследуемый от стандартного класса Stream, получить все данные (в вашем случае это js файл), найти все места где нужна замена (пометить их уникальным сочетанием, например _____please_replace_me_1_____), подставить свои значения и результат отправить в оригинальный поток (который вы предусмотрительно сохранили в экземпляре класса своего потока).

Звучит просто, но на деле нужно учитывать множество деталей которые не столь очевидны. Лучшим решением это посмотреть как устроены указанные мной middleware написанные самим Microsoft (благо в последнее время исходники можно найти на github например тут https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles, а еще тут https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression).

Изучив исходники можно попытаться создать свое решение, что я и сделал https://github.com/bopohaa/ResponseProxy
Это расширение позволяет заменять одно слово в статическом файле js перед отдачей клиенту.

Надеюсь я вам помог.